# Bitmap TileX ONLY

Tags: android, bitmap, repeat

I want my image to repeat only in X axis.

I use this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
    l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(-2, -2));
    BitmapDrawable b = null;
    try {
        b = new BitmapDrawable(getAssets().open("pattern.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    b.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);

    l.setBackgroundDrawable(b);

    setContentView(l);
}
```

When i execute my app, bitmap repeat in X axis but i show something string in Y axis

http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/9027/rgxt.png

If i try to repeat in Y axis, it happens the same but in the X axis.

How can i repeat my image only in X axis without seeing theses vertical "lines"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your bitmap takes a `CLAMP` tilemode in Y.

I guess it's the default value.

You should define what you need for the vertical direction, since your image is to small for your background, do you want to repeat it ? or strech it ?

if you don't want any of this, but need simply another color for the space under this image, you should consider adding a one pixel horizontal line at the bottom of the image.

then let the `CLAMP` tilemode extend this color to the entire background.

more information on this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#attr_android%3atileMode)

Comment: I can't use TileMode.DISABLE. That mode doesn't exit by code :S. I have tryed to pass -1 to setTileModeY() but it only accept a TileMode...

Comment: yeah sry there is no 'disable',  my mistake. I've checked, you need to set a tilemode otherwise nothing will define what to disaply on the background under the image. Use CLAMP but with a one pixelline color under the image it will work as a charm ;)

Comment: It's work! I would prefer not to have to add one transparent pixel but at this moment there isn't another solution. Thanks for your answer!