# Using pattern as a background

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:src="@drawable/header_background">

</bitmap>
```

I am using the following as a background for the action bar. The code gives me the following image:

[image]

How is there gaps on the image ? Can someone please help.

header_background:

[image]

Comment: seems that your image "header_background" have a round corners and some  padding

Comment: it appears that your background "tile" has edges with shadowing,etc. Can you include the header_background image in this post?

Comment: remove the shadow in the image and no padding will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the image to remove the shadow outline. It needs to be a flat image, so that when it is tiled, it will be visually seamless.

See this example:

[image]

Also, you might be interested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422365/bitmap-tilex-only) regarding tiling along the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

remove the android titlemode = repeat

Comment: No, the tile image should repeat. The issue is the image itself.

Comment: check your image then. there must be some shadow extra white space attached to it

Comment: Exactly. that is why several contributors are saying to remove the shadow from the image. Image is most likely a PNG file with a transparent shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just make this a 9patch that scales like you are looking to do with horizontal tiling?

[image]